# iterating through a nested list of strings to get first item

Tags: python, pandas, loops, nested-lists

I'm trying to extract items from column `gen` in a dataframe (sample below). My goal is to iterate through every line in `gen` into a new dataframe column with items matching the predefined list `genre_code`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [620, 843, 986], 'tit': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'], 'gen': [['Romance', 'Satire', 'Fiction'], ['Science Fiction', 'Novel'], ['Mystery', 'Novel']]})

genre_code = ['Science Fiction', 'Mystery', 'Non-fiction']
```

So far I was able to come up with the following:

```
new_gen = []
for i in df['gen']:
  for j in i:
    if j in genre_code:
      new_gen.append(j)
    else:
      new_gen.append('NA')
df['gen'] = new_gen
```

which does iterate through the column but the lenght of resulting `new_gen` does not match  the original dataframe row length.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index)
    746     if len(data) != len(index):
    747         raise ValueError(
--> 748             "Length of values "
    749             f"({len(data)}) "
    750             "does not match length of index "

ValueError: Length of values (30004) does not match length of index (12841)
```

I know this must be something very basic, but could someone please point me what I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the list to a string and then use `series.str.findall` to return the matching genre_code:

```
df['new_gen'] = df['gen'].astype(str).str.findall('|'.join(genre_code))
```

---

```
print(df)

    id  tit                         gen            new_gen
0  620  AAA  [Romance, Satire, Fiction]                 []
1  843  BBB    [Science Fiction, Novel]  [Science Fiction]
2  986  CCC            [Mystery, Novel]          [Mystery]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to filter `gen` column based on your list, you can do:

```
df["gen"] = df["gen"].apply(lambda x: [g for g in x if g in genre_code])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    id  tit                gen
0  620  AAA                 []
1  843  BBB  [Science Fiction]
2  986  CCC          [Mystery]
```

---

P.S: To speed up the process, you can convert `genre_code` to `set()` before:

```
genre_code = set(["Science Fiction", "Mystery", "Non-fiction"])
df["gen"] = df["gen"].apply(lambda x: [g for g in x if g in genre_code])
```